# How to clear localstorage values in javascript

Tags: javascript

How to clear only particular local storage values.Example If i have 6 localstorage values like sample1 to sample6.
localstorage clear values:

```
localStorage.setItem('sample1','');
localStorage.setItem('sample2','');
localStorage.setItem('sample3','');
localStorage.setItem('sample4','');
localStorage.setItem('sample5','');
localStorage.setItem('sample6','');
```

Can i do like this instead of above script? but not working

```
 localStorage.setItem('sample1,sample2,sample3,sample4,sample5,sample6','');
```

Any simple method is there?

Comment: Why not use a loop?

Comment: `['sample1', 'sample2', 'sample3', 'sample4', 'sample5', 'sample6'].forEach(k=>{delete localStorage[k];})`

Comment: *clear*, or *delete*?

Comment: Reading the documentation for `setItem` would tell you why what you tried is not working. It doesn't accept  arbitrary number of arguments

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like suggested in the comments, use a loop to achieve that. However, `delete` operator is not the correct way to deal with it. The following should work :

```
const itemsToRemove = ['sample1', 'sample2', 'sample3', 'sample4', 'sample5', 'sample6'];

for(const item of itemsToRemove) {
  localStorage.setItem(item, ‘’);
}
```

**EDIT**

You can wrap this in a function :

```
function clearItems(list) {
  for (const item of list) {
    localStorage.setItem(item, ‘’);
  }
}

. . .

const itemsToRemove = ['sample1', 'sample2', 'sample3', 'sample4', 'sample5', 'sample6'];

clearItems(itemsToRemove);
```

Comment: Do not remove...just unset

Comment: Then just replace the `localStorage.removeItem(item)` by `localStorage.setItem(item, ‘’)`, the keys will be kept with empty values. Just edited my answer btw

Comment: @cinnan why do you want to unset them? If you call `getItem` on an item that doesn't exist, it will return null, which should be the only use case as to why you want "unset" them.

Answer (score 4):

You can put the keys into an array (as [niet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56987416/how-to-clear-localstorage-values-in-javascript/56987511#comment100509308_56987416) pointed out), loop over each one with [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach), and use [`removeItem`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/removeItem) to remove it from localStorage:

```
const keys = ['sample1','sample2','sample3','sample4','sample5','sample6']
keys.forEach(localStorage.removeItem)
```

> Note, we can use the shorthand `.forEach(localStorage.removeItem)` over `.forEach(e => localStorage.removeItem(e))` because we are only passing one element to one function, so the shorthand will do that for us.

---

Another way (as kindly proposed by [Shyrs](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4051471/shrys)) to achieve this would be to fill an `x` element long array and append an index to each element, then apply a forEach that removes each item with the given key:

```js
Array(6).fill("sample").map((a,i)=>a+(i+1)).forEach(localStorage.removeItem);
```

---

Should you want to 'unset' or 'clear' the values, use `setItem` instead:

```
const keys = ['sample1','sample2','sample3','sample4','sample5','sample6']
keys.forEach(key => localStorage.setItem(key, ''))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're removing, consider the following:

```js
for (i = 1; i <= 6; i++) localStorage.removeItem("sample" + i);
```